# filename extension in javascript

Tags: javascript, filenames

I have a code that brings me to the extension of the name of the file. It works by using a regex that matches on a ".":

```
new_name = e.timeStamp + "_." +
      EscapeHtml (file.name.replace (/ ^. *? \. ([A-zA-Z0-9] +) $ /, "$ 1"));
```

It works on simple names like this:

```
name = asdasdasd.mp3
```

But it doesn't work when the file name has more than one ".", like:

```
avi.conn.mp3
```

How would I modify my code to cope with these more complicated cases?

Comment: What is your desired output for `avi.conn.mp3`? Do you want to extract just the `mp3` or `conn.mp3`? I tried your regex, and (once I removed the white space) it returned `mp3` from `avi.conn.mp3`.

Comment: It works fine, just remove unnecessary spaces in regexp. Try it `alert('avi.conn.mp3'.replace(/^.*?\.([A-zA-Z0-9]+)$/, "$1"))​`

Answer (score 5):

Just use `.split()`:

```
var components = filename.split('.');
var extension = components[components.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

The [path module of nodejs](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/path.js) provides a better regexp:

```
var splitDeviceRe = 
    /^([a-zA-Z]:|[\\\/]{2}[^\\\/]+[\\\/][^\\\/]+)?([\\\/])?([\s\S]*?)$/;

// Regex to split the tail part of the above into [*, dir, basename, ext]
var splitTailRe = 
    /^([\s\S]+[\\\/](?!$)|[\\\/])?((?:\.{1,2}$|[\s\S]+?)?(\.[^.\/\\]*)?)$/;

function splitPath(filename) {
    // Separate device+slash from tail
    var result = splitDeviceRe.exec(filename),
        device = (result[1] || '') + (result[2] || ''),
        tail = result[3] || '';
    // Split the tail into dir, basename and extension
    var result2 = splitTailRe.exec(tail),
        dir = result2[1] || '',
        basename = result2[2] || '',
        ext = result2[3] || '';
    return [device, dir, basename, ext];
}

function extname(path) {
    return splitPath(path)[3];
}
```

Comment: tanks all, i want  for its in 1 line

new_name = e.timeStamp + "_." +
      EscapeHtml (file.name.replace (/ ^. *? \. ([A-zA-Z0-9] +) $ /, "$ 1"));

exmplte tanks